# How to properly reference JS and CSS files in node.js/express

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I've got a java script file and my stylesheet I'm trying to include to be able to use a cypher website I've made.

My File Path is

`website/` (containing app.js/html files and package json)

`website/public/css` (containing css files)

`website/public/scripts` (containing my javascript file)

When viewing them statically, everything works as intended. The JS works and the CSS works.

However when using node.js to run it dynamically they don't work however I seem to have added the right syntax for adding them.

```
app.get('/public/scripts/script.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/scripts/script.js'));
});

app.get('/public/css/styles.css',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/css/style.css'));
});
```

And my link tags in my HTML file

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">`

I'm very new to node.js and express and would appreciate the help in figuring out whats wrong with it.

All relevant files below

**app.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');


app.listen(8080), () => console.log('listening on port 8080');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/index.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

app.get('/about.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/about.html'));
})

app.get('/public/scripts/script.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/scripts/script.js'));
});

app.get('/public/css/styles.css',function(req,res){
    res.sendfile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/css/style.css'));
});

app.get('/cyphers.html', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/cyphers.html'));
})

app.get('/api/courses', (req, res) => {
    res.send([1, 2, 3]);
})
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <title> 40285570 Cyphers </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">       
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/morseCode.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/atbash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/caesarCipher.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/scripts/rot13.js"></script>
</head>
```

**my Script file**

```
    function generateRot13()
{
    var alphabet = "abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghhijkl";
    var rot13Input = document.getElementById("message").value
    var rot13Output = "";


    for(a = 0; a <= rot13Input.length; a++)
    {
        var rot13Character = rot13Input.charAt(a);

        for(b = 0; b <= 26; b++)
        {
            if(rot13Character == alphabet[b])
            {
                rot13Output += alphabet[b + 13]
                break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("generatedMessage").value = rot13Output;
    }   
};      


function generateMorseCode() 
{
    var text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890.,?!/()&:;,=+-_$@ "
    alphabet = new Array(
        ".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---",
        "-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-.","...","-","..-",
        "...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..",".----","..---","...--","....-",
        ".....","-....","--...","---..","----.","-----",".-.-.-","--..--",
        "..--..",".----.","-.-.--","-..-.","-.--.","-.--.-",".-...",
        "---...","-.-.-.","-...-",".-.-.","-....-","..--.-","...-..-",
        ".--.-."," "

    );
    var userInput = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var generatedMessage = "";


    userInput.split("");

    for(i = 0;i <= userInput.length; i++)
    {
        currentCharacter = userInput.charAt(i).toLowerCase();

        for(x = 0; x <= text.length; x++)
        {
            if(currentCharacter == text.charAt(x))
            {
                generatedMessage += alphabet[x] + " | ";
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    document.getElementById("generatedMessage").value = generatedMessage;

    document.getElementById("message").value = "";
};

function generateCaesarCypher()
{

`var caesarAlphabet = "abcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxy`zabcdefghhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

var caesarKey = document.getElementById("caesarKey").value;
var caesarInput = document.getElementById("message").value;
var caesarOutput = "";

    var integer = parseInt(caesarKey);

    for(a = 0; a <= caesarInput.length; a++)
    {
        var caesarCharacter = caesarInput.charAt(a);

        for(b = 0; b <= 26; b++)
        {
            if(caesarCharacter == caesarAlphabet[b])
            {
                caesarOutput += caesarAlphabet[b + integer];
                break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("generatedMessage").value = caesarOutput;
    }

}

function generateAtbash()
{
    var atBashInput = document.getElementById("message").value;


    var backwardsAbc = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba";
    var forwardsAbc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var generatedAtbash = "";
    backwardsAbc.split("");
    atBashInput.split("");

    for(a = 0; a <= atBashInput.length; a++)
    {
        var atBashCharacter = atBashInput.charAt(a);

        for(b = 0; b <= backwardsAbc.length; b++)
        {
            if(atBashCharacter == forwardsAbc[b])
            {
                generatedAtbash += backwardsAbc[b];
                break;
            }
        }

        document.getElementById("generatedMessage").value = generatedAtbash;

    }
};
```

Comment: I think a static folder is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `express static` to better handle what you're trying to achieve.

Sample folder structure

```
server.js
public
  image
    sample.jpg
  js
    some.js
  css
  pages
    index.html
    about.html
```

You can server static file from `public` folder like:

```
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

In your html you can link other resources like:

```
// js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/some.js"></script>

// image
src="/public/image/sample.jpg"
```

Also take a look at [`template engines`](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html)